# XCode Linker Error When Running an AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer framework

Tags: ios, xcode

so im trying out a simple app to play a simple mp3 and for some reason i get the same error no matter what i try.
it fails to run whenever i include AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer it crashes on me. but once i remove that framework, it works fine. 
please help.

this is the error i recieve..

```
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/nnamdiokeke/Desktop/Play/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x c 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 9 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 
0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/nnamdiokeke/Desktop/Play/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The code is pasted below.

Header File

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  Play
//
//  Created by Nnamdi Okeke on 9/13/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Nnamdi Okeke. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

    AVAudioPlayer *song;
    NSURL *songlink;
}

 @property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *song;

-(IBAction)play:(id)sender;

@end
```

Implementation file

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Play
//
//  Created by Nnamdi Okeke on 9/13/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Nnamdi Okeke. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>


@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    songlink = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"A4Hood" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    song = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:songlink error:nil];
    song.delegate = self;
    //[song play];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(IBAction)play:(id)sender {
    songlink = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"A4Hood" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    song = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:songlink error:nil];
    song.delegate = self;
    [song play];


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Comment: have you added AVFoundation framwork in your project?

Comment: you add the avfoundation framwork properly in your project?

Comment: yes to both.. the frame work is in my project. @RomitMewada .. do i need to programmatically implement or impot the frameworks in any way different from what is in the code above?

Comment: @VirjaRahul same message as before

Comment: @VirjaRahul ive added it.. but what the "proper procedure" incase i did something wrong

Answer (score 1):

> it fails to run whenever i include AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer

Because inclusion of header files is not enough - you have to **link agains AVFoundation.framework**, else how would the dynamic loader know where from load the symbols which are not in your binary itself? Thus you have to add the AVFoundation framework to your project in Xcode.

More on why this is necessary [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora065.html).

Comment: hi. i have added the framework to my project but still get the same problem.. do i need to programmatically implement or import the framework in any way different from my code above?

Comment: @userxxx no, adding the framework should be enough. You're missing something else...

Comment: @user1635121 well, I don't really have an idea... Do you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually having the same problem,
the compiler struggles on this:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
    #define AVF_EXPORT extern "C"
#else
    #define AVF_EXPORT extern
#endif
```

in AVAudioSettings, this define is used and is not interpreted by the compiler.
Can it be because I use some C++ in my app?

After testing, it was the problem.
To solve it, create another class where you include AVAudio and do what you have to do with your Audio.

It seems that AVAudio and C++ are not great together.
I hope It can help